# use fade effect on javascript interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a javascript function to change a word every few seconds.
This is the code:

```
<div id="changeText" >Hello</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
var text = ["Welcome", "Hi", "Sup dude"];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
setInterval(change, 5000);
function change() {
 elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
    counter++;
    if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
}
</script>
```

This works fine, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make the text fade in/fade out so it looks better?

Comment: have a look at Jquerys *.fadeIn(time)*

Comment: I think you should just use JQuery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do: fade out the text, change it, then fade it back in.

```
var text = ["Welcome", "Hi", "Sup dude"];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");

setInterval(change, 1500);

function change() {
  $(elem).fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $(elem).text(text[counter++]);

    if (counter >= text.length) {
      counter = 0;
    }

    $(elem).fadeIn('fast');
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r6h4xw5s/

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question jQuery, I assume jQuery is accepted.

In which case, change:

```
elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
```

to

```
elem.html(text[counter]).fadeOut().fadeIn();
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvbzymfh/1).

Comment: Personally I prefer to fade the text out, then change it, then fade it back in: https://jsfiddle.net/wvbzymfh/2/